# Add custom model method in Django admin

Tags: python, django

I have a model `Ad` which has a custom `add_ownership_including_ancestors` method. Like below:

**models.py**

```
class Ad(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    creator = models.ForeignKey('User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def add_ownership_including_ancestors(self, current_user_id):
        #function to add permissions to current_user and creator and their ancestors
```

**views.py**

```
class AdViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    def create():
        #here the method is called
        adInstance.add_ownership_including_ancestors(request.user.id)
```

Now this functionality works fine in normal webpage. I want the same method to be implemented in `django admin` pages whenever I create or update `ad` object from django admin pages.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override the [**`.save_model(…)`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_model) of the `ModelAdmin` for your `Ad` model:

```
from django.contrib import admin

class AdAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    
    # …
    
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)
        obj.add_ownership_including_ancestors(request.user.id)

admin.site.register(Ad, AdAdmin)
```